# How to read and write value from registry in Windows CE?

Tags: c#, registry, windows-ce

How do you insert the value `1` into the property `CDInsert` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WJST\WLAN` and read it back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Try this:

```
//using Microsoft.Win32;

RegistryKey reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\WJST\WLAN", true); 

// set value of "CDInsert" to 1
reg.SetValue("CDInsert", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

// get value of "CDInsert"; return 0 if value not found
int value = (int)reg.GetValue("CDInsert", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you try to access the key directly with `key.SetValue()` throws an exception because you don't have the rights.

You can use `Registry.SetValue()` like in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) or like following example:

```
const string root = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"; // Root of your path
const string path = @"\SOFTWARE\WJST\WLAN"; // Path of your key
const string default = "CDInsert"; // Name of the key
const string value = "1";

Registry.SetValue(root + "\\" + path, default, value);
```

Pay attention if your registry is volatile than you should flush and persist:

```
const UInt32 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002;

IntPtr hkeyLocalMachine = new IntPtr(unchecked((int)HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE ));
RegFlushKey(hkeyLocalMachine);
```

For use `RegFlushKey` you need to add an extern method:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
public static extern int RegFlushKey(IntPtr hKey);
```

Usefull links: [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/RegFlushKey.html), [regflushkey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms891455(v%3Dmsdn.10)).